# currentUser as a modelbinded parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Right now I'm thinking about a pattern to have the 'current user' as a modelbinded parameter in my actions.

My actions would look something like this:

```
public JsonResult ListStuff(User currentUser, string paramter1, int parameter2)
{
}
```

And I have a very simple ModelBinder that looks like this:

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    if ( bindingContext.ModelName == "currentUser" )
        return Globals.HttpContextItems.User;

    return null;
}
```

I really like that the action is less dependent on another Controller Property. It makes it more clear what the 'input parameters' of the functions are, it's more reusable, and will make it a bit more easily testable in the future.

I'm a bit affraid of security issues though. I probably have to make very sure (i.e. in the DefaultModelBinder) that the currentUser will never be automatically bound by other ModelBinders.

Can anyone shine a light if this might be a good pattern, and if there is stuff that I'm not thinking about at the moment, but that will give problems in the future.

Comment: I would say its an antipattern for modelbinding. Modelbinding doesn't rely on the name of the param. it relies on the type. the attribute answer is probably closer, I would allow the attribute to accept a string in its ctor though, so its not always "currentUser"

Comment: Interesting take on this. But what do you think about it in a 'convention over configuration' way? Isn't this the same thing like that you have to name your Controller SomeNameController. Or your views are in a folder called Views and found automatically?

Comment: Nothing wrong with convention over configuration. Problem is in this case the convention is to match against type. Matching by parameter name goes against the existent convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are concerned that other ModelBinders will set that parameter, why not create an ActionFilterAttribute so that you'll explicitly have to decorate your action method:

```
public class GetCurrentUserAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.ActionParameters["currentUser"] = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
[GetCurrentUser]
public ActionResult Index(User currentUser)
{
}
```

Definitely not as clean as the default model binder, but a lot more explicit.

Comment: You could make it a globacl filter.

Comment: True, but I like the idea of being able to easily determine where the value is being set.

Comment: That's pretty clever. I'm already using custom AuthorizationAttributes  everywhere for different levels of authorization. So I might change them to ActionFilterAttributes, and I can directly set the parameters in there.

Comment: I would adjust it to match [GetCurrentUser("currentUser")] so you don't have to remember the exact string for each action.  Thats just a nitpick though.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea. And I like how it keeps with IoC by injection the requirements into the method (people often forget that you can inject dependencies into methods, not just constructors).

Your security concerns would be abstracted to the location of where you would populate this context item.  My recommendation would be to put that very same logic, to populate the context item, at this same location.  Having that kind of logic in two places (a model binder, and then say a controller method) would have you chasing two places to track down a bug.  I say this model binder should be responsible for loading that context item, if it is null.

Lastly, this would abstract away even more complex "user verification" services in the future if you ever wanted to do that.  For example, I had a project requirement at one time to ensure every piece of data and ID being passed into the domain belonged to that user with a security check.  What this method you describe opens you up to is have a custom User object that inherits from you base User object, called something like `UserContext : User` that can have a number of additional UI related functions and properties on it - including addition security boolean verifications.

I may try this in my next project.